# dealing with time in r difference between two times

Tags: r, datetime

I have two columns

```
starttime                      endtime
2019-11-05 18:02:04            2019-11-05 00:02:04
2019-08-02 20:18:00            2019-0802  01:10:00
2019-12-07 17:28:00            2019-12-07 18:00:00
```

I am trying to find the difference in time between starttime and endtime

`mutate(col = difftime(endtime,starttime,units = "hours")`

but i am getting negative hours which makes no sense, and i need it to be endtime - startime because it would mess up things for the dataframe that I have I beleive that 0.533 is right I got
col
-18
-19
0.533

Comment: Since `starttime` is greater than `endtime` in first two rows you get negative numbers. What is your expected output ?

Comment: since 18:00 is essentially 6:00 pm and 00:00 is midnight, I would expect the output to be 6 hours difference, is there a way to change all the 00:00 in my data set to 24:00 then that would make the calculation easier? or if there is another way to deal with this please let me know

Comment: Not clear to me what you are trying to do (you also haven't shown the expected output). If you turn 00 to 24 what about the next row where you have 01, would that be 25 then?

Comment: At midnight the date changes. Objectively `2019-11-05 00:02:04` is before `2019-11-05 18:02:04` by about 18 hours. You can add a day to your end time to make it `2019-11-06 18:02:04` which is 6 hours after the start time (on the next day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can increment the `endtime` by 1 day if `startttime > endtime` and then use `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(endtime = if_else(starttime > endtime, endtime + 86400, endtime), 
         col = difftime(endtime,starttime,units = "hours"))

#            starttime             endtime             col
#1 2019-11-05 18:02:04 2019-11-06 00:02:04 6.0000000 hours
#2 2019-08-02 20:18:00 2019-08-03 01:10:00 4.8666667 hours
#3 2019-12-07 17:28:00 2019-12-07 18:00:00 0.5333333 hours
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(starttime = structure(c(1572976924, 1564777080, 
1575739680), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
endtime = structure(c(1572912124, 1564708200, 1575741600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you this works! exactly what I have been looking for! appreciate this